# How do you make a graphic rectangle in a c console window?

Tags: c, graphics

I would like to know how to make a graphic rectangle in c (by that I mean a real rectangle, not just a bunch of asterisks).  By the way, I can't use Borland's graphics.h.

Answer (score 2):

In a console window you can't draw lines (graphics) because the console is running
in text mode, you can display only ASCII characters.

The [extended ASCII](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/files/ascii.htm) contains characters which can be used to display rectangles.

179 `│`
191 `┐`
192 `└`
196 `─`
217 `┘`
218 `┌`

Example

```
┌─────────┐  
│         │
└─────────┘
```

In the above rectangle there are visible gaps between some characters
but in text mode these special chars are displayed differently, with no gaps.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to run the console in graphics mode.

Comment: @smilinggoomba: you'll have to find a library for that job. In the past, I was using Borland's BGI mode (driver). Nowadays, I don't use that kind of libraries. Instead, I use window surfaces, directx, cairo etc.

Comment: (under GNU/Linux) the framebuffer library [fbdev](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) can show graphics in a console, like e.g. textual browser w3m does.

Comment: @Shin, I'm not familiar with fbdev, but looks interesting. Good link.

Comment: I made a function that displays a rectangle of programmer-given size using those rectangle characters.

Comment: @smilinggoomba, nice. They are not perfect for drawing graphics but it's better than nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches. You can use API of your operating system (e.g. MS Windows API, or using Xlib API for many graphical environment using "X11"). But this is not a portable approach.

Then you can stick to a library that exists for several OS; examples of portable library that you can find on several OSs are the [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) library, [cairo](http://cairographics.org/) library, an [OpenGL](http://www.mesa3d.org/) based library (maybe too much for 2D gfx, though you can use it too), GUI toolkits like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) can help too, or even the [GNU plot library](http://www.gnu.org/s/plotutils/), depending on exactly what you mean by graphic rectangle.

Likely the [cairo](http://cairographics.org/) library is the best fit to your problem.

Comment: if you want to try the character-graphics Dandoulakis talks about (after checking what your terminal can accept as encoding, which is not trivial usually), and if you are on a "unix"-like system, then you could give a try to [(n)curses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) which would allow you to create interfaces like [this](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/sles9/adminguide-sles9/images/yast2_ncurses_main.png) (the inner part) in a terminal

Comment: Is it possible to use a pointer to write the color of a pixel directly to video memory (0xb8000)?

Comment: usually it shouldn't be allowed (by the system) for "normal" applications (moreover I believe it is not that easy with modern gfx cards, unless some legacy mode is active; and of course it is less efficient); libraries to do something like that exist, e.g. linux framebuffer

Comment: Actually, I'll give SDL a try.

Answer (score 0):

we draw rectangle in borland compiler by using **#include<graphics.h>**
use syntax-

**rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2);**

x1,y1,x2 and y2 is the four coordinate of vertex of rectangle.